# How to escape "/" in a route parameter?

Tags: react-router

If I have a route:

```
<Route path="Admin/Products/Edit/:id" ... />
```

and I have a callsite such as:

```
const productId = "products/12345";
return <Link to="/Admin/Products/Edit/" + productId>...</Link>
```

How do I escape `productId` so that react-router captures the whole value, including the slash as a single value?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few ways of doing this:

1. You could do something like:

```jsx
<Route path='Admin/Products/Edit/*' component={EditProduct} />
```

then you could use `this.props.params.splat` to get your: "products/12345", problem with that is that `*` matches all characters (non-greedy).

2. Or maybe something a bit more strict like:

```jsx
<Route path='Admin/Products/Edit/*/*/' component={EditProduct} />
```

then you need to remember that your `Link`s path needs to end with `/`, e.g.:

```jsx
const productId = "products/12345/";
return <Link to="/Admin/Products/Edit/" + productId>...</Link>
```

and you get an array of splats, so you could do: `this.props.params.splat.join('/')` to get your: "products/12345"

You can find more about [Route Matching in the docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteMatching.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the route parameter before you pass it to the route and it will force the forward slash to be escaped:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();
const id = "products/12345";

navigate(`Admin/Products/Edit/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`);
```

It will automatically be un-escaped along with the other characters as normal in the target component:

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const { id } = useParams();

// Will output "products/12345"
console.log(id);
```