# What's the way to handle paths with slash via react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a problem with dynamic routing with react-router. My example path looks like this :

```
/contacts/C/BG-DPC-063
```

And this is my route:

```
<Route path='/contacts/:contactId' component={Contacts}/>
```

So when I'm trying to handle my match:

```
const {
    params: { contactId }
} = match;
```

contactId is just 'C' because of the slash. How can I handle this? This is ID from API so I can't change this.

Comment: If you need a forward slash (a reserved character) within a path component (where it has a reserved purpose), it should be *encoded*: `/contacts/C%2fBG-DPC-063`.

Comment: I´d say you need to escape the slash character:
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319913/how-to-escape-in-a-route-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
<Route path='/contacts/:contactPrefix/:contactSuffix' component={Contacts}/>
```

Then you merge them later?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends which parts of URL are dynamic? If "C" is not dynamic

```
<Route path='/contacts/C/:contactId' component={Contacts}/>
```

otherwise

```
<Route path='/contacts/:apiID/:contactID' component={Contacts}/>
```

If second example is the case, be sure to handle non-existing `appID` and/or `contactID` case because user can enter anything valid/invalid for `:appID` and/or `:contactID` in URL (if its invalid, redirect him to other page or show some message).